# BezierPath Rotation in a UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, bezier, uibezierpath

I am drawing a BezierPath on Touch event. Now I have to rotate that Bezier Path on the same location using Gesture Method. But problem is, after rotation its position become change. Its look like the following image.. How can I fix this?

[image: BezierPath Drawing]

The Upper image is the original image.
Share your ideas with me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this in [Apple documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html)

`applyTransform:`
Transforms all points in the path using the specified affine transform matrix.

```
- (void)applyTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
```

I haven't tried this. But here is how to rotate a `NSBezierPath` from the link [rotating-nsbezierpath-objects](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/318293-rotating-nsbezierpath-objects.html). Try to use the similar approach on `UIBezierPath`.

```
- (NSBezierPath*)rotatedPath:(CGFloat)angle aboutPoint:(NSPoint)cp
{
// return a rotated copy of the receiver. The origin is taken as point <cp> relative to the original path.
// angle is a value in radians

if( angle == 0.0 )
  return self;
else
{
  NSBezierPath* copy = [self copy];

  NSAffineTransform* xfm = RotationTransform( angle, cp );
  [copy transformUsingAffineTransform:xfm];

  return [copy autorelease];
}
}
```

which uses:

```
NSAffineTransform *RotationTransform(const CGFloat angle, const NSPoint cp)
{
// return a transform that will cause a rotation about the point given at the angle given

NSAffineTransform* xfm = [NSAffineTransform transform];
[xfm translateXBy:cp.x yBy:cp.y];
[xfm rotateByRadians:angle];
[xfm translateXBy:-cp.x yBy:-cp.y];

return xfm;
}
```

Comment: Link for the tutorial is dead