# Rotate CGPath without changing its position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I want to rotate a `CGPath`, I'm using the following code:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleInRadians);
CGPathRef rotatedPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(myPath, &transform);
```

This code works fine but it changes path's position! I want the path remain at the same position as it was before rotating.

Comment: The path is going to rotate around some point. It has to. What point do you think it should rotate around? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: I believe the path will rotate around (0, 0). You could make your transform translate the center to (0,0) then rotate and then transform back.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A path doesn't have “a position”.  A path is a set of points (defined by line and curve segments).  Every point has its own position.

Perhaps you want to rotate the path around a particular point, instead of around the origin.  The trick is to create a composite transform that combines three individual transforms:

1. Translate the origin to the rotation point.
2. Rotate.
3. Invert the translation from step 1.

For example, here's a function that takes a path and returns a new path that is the original path rotated around the center of its bounding box:

```
static CGPathRef createPathRotatedAroundBoundingBoxCenter(CGPathRef path, CGFloat radians) {
    CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path); // might want to use CGPathGetPathBoundingBox
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, center.x, center.y);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, radians);
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -center.x, -center.y);
    return CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(path, &transform);
}
```

Note that this function returns a new path with a +1 retain count that you are responsible for releasing when you're done with it.  For example, if you're trying to rotate the path of a shape layer:

```
- (IBAction)rotateButtonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    CGPathRef path = createPathRotatedAroundBoundingBoxCenter(shapeLayer_.path, M_PI / 8);
    shapeLayer_.path  = path;
    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

#### UPDATE

Here's a demonstration using a Swift playground.  We'll start with a helper function that displays a path and marks the origin with a crosshair:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

func showPath(label: String, path: UIBezierPath) {
    let graph = UIBezierPath()
    let r = 40
    graph.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:0,y:r))
    graph.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:0,y:-r))
    graph.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:-r,y:0))
    graph.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:r,y:0))
    graph.appendPath(path)
    XCPCaptureValue(label, graph)
}
```

Next, here's our test path:

```
var path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:1000,y:1000))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:1000,y:1200))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:1100,y:1200))
showPath("original", path)
```

[image: original path]

(Remember, the crosshair is the origin and is not part of the path we're transforming.)

We get the center and transform the path so it's centered at the origin:

```
let bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path.CGPath)
let center = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(bounds), y:CGRectGetMidY(bounds))

let toOrigin = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-center.x, -center.y)
path.applyTransform(toOrigin)
showPath("translated center to origin", path)
```

[image: path translated to origin]

Then we rotate it.  All rotations happen around the origin:

```
let rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI / 3.0))
path.applyTransform(rotation)
showPath("rotated", path)
```

[image: path rotated]

Finally, we translate it back, exactly inverting the original translation:

```
let fromOrigin = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(center.x, center.y)
path.applyTransform(fromOrigin)
showPath("translated back to original center", path)
```

[image: path translated from origin]

Note that we must **invert the original translation**.  We don't translate by the center of its new bounding box.  Recall that (in this example), the original center is at (1050,1100).  But after we've translated it to the origin and rotated it, the new bounding box's center is at (-25,0).  Translating the path by (-25,0) will not put it anywhere close to its original position!

Comment: Bounding box will change during rotation let's say for 45 degrees, then you will end up with different dimensions bezier path. So to undo the translation you would probably have to get new bounding box and inverse using new origin. Inverting with old center won't work, as path bounds may grow after rotation.

Comment: Undoing the translation means doing exactly the opposite of the original translation.  You don't want to look at the new bounding box.  You must transform the path by the inverse of the original translating transformation.

Comment: @Andy I've updated my answer to show the process step-by-step.

Comment: @robmayoff terrific post, thanks a lot for this update with Playground. I probably mixed things here. I was trying to rotate bezier path and render it in image. For that I had to reset translation to make sure bezier path fits into image bounds. So I essentially used (x, y) from bezierPath.bounds to undo the translation.

Comment: really helpfull!!! Thanks, man ! I have spend 5-6 hours to understand that i need to rotate bazier path instead of whole layer

Comment: Brilliant answer!  I've got the same problem and nearly give up, and then I found your answer!  thank you!

Answer (score 12):

A Swift 5 version:

```
func rotate(path: UIBezierPath, degree: CGFloat) {
    let bounds: CGRect = path.cgPath.boundingBox
    let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)

    let radians = degree / 180.0 * .pi
    var transform: CGAffineTransform = .identity
    transform = transform.translatedBy(x: center.x, y: center.y)
    transform = transform.rotated(by: radians)
    transform = transform.translatedBy(x: -center.x, y: -center.y)
    path.apply(transform)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Swift 3 method to rotate a rectangle in place around its center:

```
func createRotatedCGRect(rect: CGRect, radians: CGFloat) -> CGPath {
    let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
    path.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: center.x, y: center.y).inverted())
    path.apply(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians))
    path.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: center.x, y: center.y))
    return path.cgPath
}
```

All of rob mayoff's code for applying this to a path and its bounding box would still apply, so I didn't see cause to repeat them.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to rotate and/or scale an UIBezierPath, or scale a CAShapeLayer while keep the center of the UIBezierPath. Here the function for Swift 4/5. It is based on answer from rob mayoff.

```
extension UIBezierPath {
 
/// perform scale on UIBezierPath and keep the position in the path's center
  func scale(scale:CGFloat) {
    let bounds = self.cgPath.boundingBox
    
    let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.midX,y:bounds.midY)
    var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: center.x, y: center.y)
    transform = transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
    transform = transform.translatedBy(x: -center.x, y: -center.y);
    
    self.apply(transform)
  }


  /// perform rotate on UIBezierPath and keep the center unchanged
  func rotate(radians:CGFloat) {
    let bounds = self.cgPath.boundingBox
    
    let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.midX,y:bounds.midY)
    var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.translatedBy(x: center.x, y: center.y)
    transform = transform.rotated(by: radians)
    transform = transform.translatedBy(x: -center.x, y: -center.y);
    
    self.apply(transform)
  }
}
```